# D3.js In Action, code example not working

Tags: d3.js

I copied an example from the book *D3.js In Action* for a simple bar chart and get an error when I try to run it.

Console error:

```
charts.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined
```

The code:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 390]).range([0,100]);

d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('rect')
    .data([150,390,340,295])
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
    .attr('width', 50)
    .attr('height', function(d) { return yScale(d); })
    .attr('x', function(d, i) { return i*60; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return 100 - yScale(d); })
    .style('fill', 'rgb(104, 167, 207)');
```

If I move the `yScale` declaration to the bottom I get the following error:

```
charts.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: yScale is not a function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely using D3 v4 whereas the example is build on v3. Because v4, in contrast to v3, is now modular the namespaces got flattened. According to the [change log](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale) for the linear scale this means:

> - d3.scale.linear ↦ [d3.scaleLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleLinear)

Since `d3.scale` is undefined there is no property `.linear` to be read from it, hence the error. Change your code to

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 390]).range([0,100]);
```

to get it working.

Comment: thanks, that removed the first error. Now I get:
Uncaught TypeError: yScale is not a function
Is there an updated way to pass yScale the data 'd'?

Comment: @RonI In your question you mentioned moving the declaration to the bottom. Have you since moved it back to above the position where it is first used? If yScale is not yet assigned, it is certainly not a function, just as the error stated